# Enviar un mensaje despues de usar la funcion load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando la función `load()` para traer una tabla de información. En esta tabla tengo en cada fila un botón para editar la información correspondiente a esta, al momento de hacer clic en el botón «editar» envió mediante **AJAX** el `id` de la información correspondiente para editar y cargo esta información dentro un "MODAL" (hasta ahí vamos bien).

Donde viene mi inconveniente es una vez que se envía la información nueva; si hay algún tipo de error me lo muestra dentro de mi "MODAL", pero al momento de actualizar la información cierro el modal y cargo nuevamente la tabla de información para que la información aparezca actualizada, pero estoy tratando de enviar un mensaje para cuando la página se actualice.

```
$(this).modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();

$("#tableInsurance").load('aseguradora/tableInsurance.php');            
$('.msg').html("<div class='alert alert-success fade in'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><span id='message'></span></div>");
$('#message').append(data.msg);
```

Cierro el modal que abrí para insertar la información, una vez que cierra cargo la tabla de nuevo y "envió el mensaje", el mensaje nunca llega... he dado mente y no llego a una solución.

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'status' => 2,
    'msg' => "Se ha actualizado con éxito."
));
```

Esto se envía desde donde se actualiza la información.. me funciona perfectamente si lo cargo dentro del "modal".

Comment: Hola Jorge, ese es todo el codigo? por que de donde sale `data.msg`. Entiendo que `msg` es la parte de la respuesta, pero no veo donde lo estas solicitando al servidor. Puede explicar esta parte?

Comment: Disculpen la tardanza mi problema consistía en que cuando al momento de actualizar quería hacer aparecer un mensaje dentro de una archivo el cual se cargaba con la función, pasaba que al momento de enviar el mensaje el archivo cargaba y el mensaje se "perdia", lo solucione de la siguiente manera agregando el mensaje encima del "div" que carga tabla y conseguí el resultado que quería. Se le agradece su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo muy clara la duda, pero el método `load()` acepta un `callback`:

```
$("#tableInsurance").load('aseguradora/tableInsurance.php', function() {
  // tableInsurance.php ha cargado
})
```

Comment: Disculpen la tardanza mi problema consistía en que cuando al momento de actualizar quería hacer aparecer un mensaje dentro de una archivo el cual se cargaba con la función, pasaba que al momento de enviar el mensaje el archivo cargaba y el mensaje se "perdia", lo solucione de la siguiente manera agregando el mensaje encima del "div" que carga tabla y conseguí el resultado que quería. Se le agradece su tiempo.

Comment: @JorgeD.Jesus: Considera publicar tu solución como respuesta. Los comentarios son temporales  y no se destacan por lo que podrían pasar desapercibidos a alguien que tenga un problema similar al tuyo.